# Wiring a European range

Tags: electrical, range

My brother just bought a Fagor range for his kitchen. The range came pre-wired(less the plug) with a red, black and green wire. The range is 240v, 15 amp. The wiring instructions read: red is hot (240v),black is neutral and green ground. Which is how it would be wired in Europe. My question is how do I wire this here in the states? Thanks.

Comment: Relevant (NEMA 6-15): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector

Answer (score 2):

Does the range have 120/240 volt hookup instructions?  They might be inside the access port where the pigtail ("cord") is wired into the range.  The hookup instructions are the authority.

However, lacking any instructions, this is likely to work:

Connect the hot (red) to the U.S. red, the "neutral" (black) to the U.S. black wire.  That provides 240 volts to the heating coils.  Connect the ground to the green.  Leave the U.S. white wire ***un***connected to anything in the range.

The range does not use 120 volts for anything (timer, appliance outlet), so the white wire is not connected.

---

There is a *slight* danger that the appliance manufacturer has somehow assumed that ground and "neutral" are at the same voltage.  (They should not have, but there could be an assumption that ground to neutral is not more than a few volts different.)  If so, connecting the range might blow an internal fuse or the house's panel circuit breaker.  For this reason, do *not* plug the range into the outlet with the breaker on.  Instead, after plugging it in, turn the range on at the breaker.

---

I tried to find a user manual, but Fagor's website is *trying* to be "smart" and routes my U.S.-based IP to something they think would be suitable.  Alas, it persistently picks a Spanish language enterprise-wide "under construction" stub site.

http://www.fagoramerica.com/my_fagor/user_manuals still might be useful.  Have a look with the specific model number.

Answer (score -1):

Well with 240v U.S wiring in an older house for a range (240V)The colors of the wires in the wall are black L1 , white L2 and copper ground to The connection that has a bent or L shaped outlet are used. If it is a newer home it requires 4 wires usually black, red are hot (240V) then white neutral and green or copper goes to the equipment ground (frame) of the range. to get 240V depending on the type of wiring in the wall this is how to hook it up on a range 240V outlet.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. If he connects the white wire to neutral, the range will get 120V instead of 240V.

Comment: Your "newer home" comment about a 4-wire circuit only applies to 120/240V appliances. This is a straight 240V appliance.

Comment: The only appliance that the 2014 NEC considers not to have a neutral load is a water heater newer homes require the 4 wire outlet as I described.

Comment: @EdBeal, do you have the code section for that one?

Comment: It comes from 220.61 for neutral load calculations water heaters are omitted because there is no neutral load. Ranges, cook tops counter mounted cooking units and dryers are all listed.

Comment: OK, but what does that have to do with running the branch circuit? Are you saying that section on load calcs says we need to run a neutral even if one is not needed?

Comment: Yes it has been that way since 99. maybe longer that is the oldest book I have here ( 250.140).  Similar to the new requirement for a neutral to be run to the devices in a 3 way switches. I don't need that neutral but code requires it. For existing dwellings the 3 wire branch circuit can be used. The last comment would be is the range the OP is inquiring about listed for use in the U.S. some equipment from other country's create a fire hazard when connected to 60 Hz and different nominal voltages than the country they were designed for.

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong. There is NO requirement that a neutral be run to a.household appliance that does not require one. This is nothing like the neutral run to a.switch requirement. I'm not sure where you got this interpretation from but you were misinformed.